# Difference between Eclipse CDT ast and model packages

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse CDT to analyse C/C++ source code as part of a research project. I noticed that CDT's [API](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fast%2Fcpp%2Fpackage-summary.html) has two packages of "accessible" interfaces:

(1) Package [org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fast%2Fpackage-summary.html&cp=13_1_0_1)

(2) Package [org.eclipse.cdt.core.model](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/package-summary.html?cp=13_1_0_0)

I assume that (1) is for AST traversal, but what is the purpose of (2)?

Answer (score 0):

The "model" is a less detailed model of the source code than the AST. It models entities like variables, functions, classes, and preprocessor directives, but not other things like statements and expressions. It's used for generating the Outline View, the contents of the Project Explorer, and entries in some other views like Call Hierarchy and Type Hierarchy.

I believe the model pre-dates the AST, and at least some of its uses could be rewritten to use the AST instead.